# Why does CoxPH always underperforming vs a simple Kaplan Meier?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier, actuarial-science

For context, my company have outsourced a lifetime prediction to a big firm. The goal is to predict lifetimes of a categorical variable.
The data includes customers from 2012 to 2022. I have the survival times. If the customer is still with us, they get censored in 2022 (today). There is only 1 categorical covariate with 6 categories (dummy Variables).

Big Firm's Model:

1. Generate KM curves for each (Category + Cohort) where Cohort is (Year-month-01). For example, category_3|2015-05-01.
2. For each Category, get an average of the (Category + Cohort) KM curves to get 1 single KM curve per category. The average is an exponentially weighted average to give recent Cohorts more importance.

My model:
I have used CPH with breslow estimation for baseline hazard. Covariates include the categorical covariate, cohort year, cohort month.

Validation:
Artificial censoring: I will artificially censor the data at a specific date, for example 2019-01-01. Train both models on this. Then I will try to predict survival/retention at 2021-01-01 of the customers who were still with us at 2019-01-01. Then I find the error, Predicted Retention - Actual Retention for analysis.
Edit: This is just one date for validation. I have used various dates for validation and got the same results

Results:
KM curves are always correctly predicting retention while CoxPH overestimates the retention by alot. Cox = .55 vs KM = .42 vs acutal = .4. I have tried using "sample_weights" column to give more importance to recent customers but to no avail.

Is there any underlying issue?

Comment: Have you documented whether the assumptions of the Cox model have been met?

Comment: I have not. Can that really affect the lifetime predictions? Its just Maximizing the likelihood. I am not interested in inference.

Comment: Yes, even with only categorical covariates. Categorical covariates won't pose a problem with the linearity assumption, but they might with the assumption of proportional hazards (PH). If the association of a categorical covariate with outcome changes over time (i.e., non-PH) but your model doesn't allow for that, then your predictions might not be correct. Plots of scaled Schoenfeld residuals over time are a good way to evaluate that problem.